# strange implementation of acosf

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, floating-point, language-lawyer

I stumbled about some strange problem:

I got floating point exceptions (we enabled them explicitly and used /fp:strict)in acosf:

we have 2 32bit floating point vectors and want to calculate the angle.

```
float32 len1 = Vec_Len(vec1);
float32 len2 = Vec_Len(vec2);
float32 angle = acosf( (vec1.x * vec2.x + vec1.y * vec2.y)/(len1*len2) );
```

Quite straight forward.
The Problem that occurred was an invalid Op exception.
Checking the Values of the calulation revealed that the expression in the `acosf` call evaluates to a `double` (remember: in C floating point expressions are always promoted to double) value slightly greater than `1.0` (welcome to the world of floating point math).
So far so good - *BUT* the expression rounded to float32 precision is exactly `1.0f` (i also checked the binary representation).

So why the hell would trigger `acosf` this exception? Should not the expression be truncated/rounded/what ever to float32 on parameter passing?

After short thinking: i found this in the "Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\math.h":

```
#define acosf(x)    ((float)acos((double)(x)))
```

this is one of the definitions in the file but it is the one that seems to be active since i can see this in the preprocessed file.

Is this 'legal'?
It seems to me that this violates the "as-if" rule.

This definition (that is also in the file) seems more appropriate to me

```
inline float acosf(_In_ float _X)
        {return ((float)acos((double)_X)); }
```

Comment: Try `angle = (acosf)(...);`. The extra parenthesis around the function name disable macro expansion.  ... even better: get rid of `float` and do everything in `double`.

Comment: getting rid of floats is not an option since we use them on purpose. our target architecture only supports 32bit floats

Comment: @pmg putting the `acosf` in parentheses of course does not help, since it is the way the stdlib implements the `acosf`. putting it in parentheses results in compiler errors.

Comment: See [C11 7.1.4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.4): "... Any macro definition of a function can be suppressed locally ...". Your compiler is not Standards compliant :(

Comment: @pmg i did not get your point. The stdlib has to implement a set of defined functions. if it implements them as macro aliases to other functions or not should not matter as long they behave like specified. Sure if they `#define` it and you force the suppression of the macro-substitution of that call - why should this be a compiler issue.

The issue in my opinion is, that the macro does not enforce the truncation of the parameter into a float. Like `#define acosf(x)    ((float)acos((float)(x)))`

Comment: My point is that a standard compliant compiler has to have `acosf()` properly defined (so that you can use its address). The macro does not do any argument conversion; the function call converts arguments to the proper type. `acosf(1.00000000000000000001)` when called as a function converts the `double` argument to `float` type.

Comment: Maybe you could ask your compiler implementors (file a Microsoft bug report) to redefine the macro as `#define acosf(x) ((float)acos((double)((float)(x))))`.

Comment: "C floating point expressions are always promoted to double" -- No, they are not.  This rules for evaluating float expressions depend on the value of FLT_EVAL_METHOD, and vary between compilers.  Broadly speaking, I agree with you that `acosf(x)` should be defined as `(float)acos((double)(float)x)` if they aren't going to have an actual function, but Visual Studio has historically not shown the slightest hint of being concerned with C standard conformance.